# Correctly storing a Rust Rc<T> in C-managed memory

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm wrapping a Rust object to be used from Lua.  I need the object to be destroyed when neither Rust code nor Lua still has a reference to it, so the obvious (to me) solution is to use `Rc<T>`, stored in Lua-managed memory.

The Lua API (I'm using [rust-lua53](https://github.com/jcmoyer/rust-lua53) for now) lets you allocate a chunk of memory and attach methods and a finalizer to it, so I want to store an `Rc<T>` into that chunk of memory.

My current attempt looks like.  First, creating an object:

```
/* Allocate a block of uninitialized memory to use */
let p = state.new_userdata(mem::size_of::<Rc<T>>() as size_t) as *mut Rc<T>;
/* Make a ref-counted pointer to a Rust object */
let rc = Rc::<T>::new(...);
/* Store the Rc */
unsafe { ptr::write(p, rc) };
```

And in the finaliser:

```
let p: *mut Rc<T> = ...; /* Get a pointer to the item to finalize */
unsafe { ptr::drop_in_place(p) };  /* Release the object */
```

Now this seems to work (as briefly tested by adding a println!() to the `drop` method).  But is it correct and safe (as long as I make sure it's not accessed after finalization)?  I don't feel confident enough in unsafe Rust to be sure that it's ok to ptr::write an `Rc<T>`.

I'm also wondering about, rather than storing an `Rc<T>` directly, storing an `Option<Rc<T>>`; then instead of `drop_in_place()` I would `ptr::swap()` it with `None`.  This would make it easy to handle any use after finalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now this seems to work (as briefly tested by adding a println!() to the drop method). But is it correct and safe (as long as I make sure it's not accessed after finalisation)? I don't feel confident enough in unsafe Rust to be sure that it's ok to ptr::write an `Rc<T>`.

Yes, you may `ptr::write` any Rust type to any memory location. This "leaks" the `Rc<T>` object, but writes a bit-equivalent to the target location.

When using it, you need to guarantee that no one modified it outside of Rust code and that you are still in the same thread as the one where it was created. If you want to be able to move across threads, you need to use `Arc`.

Rust's thread safety cannot protect you here, because you are using raw pointers.

---

> I'm also wondering about, rather than storing an `Rc<T>` directly, storing an `Option<Rc<T>>`; then instead of drop_in_place() I would ptr::swap() it with None. This would make it easy to handle any use after finalisation.

The pendant to `ptr::write` is `ptr::read`. So if you can guarantee that no one ever tries to `ptr::read` or `drop_in_place()` the object, then you can just call `ptr::read` (which returns the object) and use that object as you would use any other `Rc<T>` object. You don't need to care about dropping or anything, because now it's back in Rust's control.

---

You should also be using `new_userdata_typed` instead of `new_userdata`, since that takes the memory handling off your hands. There are other convenience wrapper functions ending with the postfix `_typed` for most userdata needs.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.
So am I right in saying that `ptr::drop_in_place(p);` is logically the same as if you ignore the result of `ptr::read(p)`, except for copying a few bits in the latter case?

Comment: Agreed about `new_userdata_typed`, which is what I'm actually using, but I tried (possibly misguidedly) to use a simpler interface to simplify the question...

Comment: yep, `drop_in_place` and `read` have the same semantics if `read`'s return value is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work; of course, note that the `drop_in_place(p)` will just decrease the counter of the `Rc` and only drop the contained `T` if and only if it was the last reference, which is the correct action.

Comment: isn't this more of a comment/edit to the question? @Chris Emerson noted that it's not his actual code, but he's using the generic method `new_userdata_typed`, which prevents such C-ish mistakes

Comment: @ker: I would say it's an answer (though not as elaborate as yours), in that it answers the *But is it correct and safe (as long as I make sure it's not accessed after finalization)?* question. Or is the issue that I actually start by fixing the code before answering the question so the last part is not that visible?

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I'll edit and fix the question.